# FBConnect (IPHONE) , custom publish dialog

Tags: iphone, facebook, dialog, textfield, fbconnect

is possible custominzing the FBdialog??, i have already modify the attachment on the dialog when the user wants to publish a post; but i need to make hidden the textfield that the dialog presents...there is a way to access to this property or it's just a webView that load a page from facebook's server?

sorry for my bad english!

thanks in advance

Comment: Did any answer help you? Just click the check mark to mark it as an accepted solution or vote it up. And please check your other questions for possible solutions, too. Thanks! :)   (And yes, this is copy-pasted so new users are aware of the voting system.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. just design your own UI and pass the message to a method containing this code:

```
NSString *message = @"test message here";
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[params setObject:message forKey:@"message"];
[params setObject:toID forKey:@"target_id"];
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.Stream.publish" params:params];
```

Comment: thank for your reply..!
..but if i want just hidden the textfield without recreate my own instance of FBStreamDialog ..is possible?

Comment: it's the same functionality behind the FBStreamDialog. Just try it.